# Python lxml: Items without .text attribute returned when querying for nodes()

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to parse out certain tags from an XML document and it is retiring  an `AttributeError: '_ElementStringResult' object has no attribute 'text'` error.

Here is the xml document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<Root>
  <Data>
    <FormType>Log</FormType>
    <Submitted>2012-03-19 07:34:07</Submitted>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <LAST>SJTK4</LAST>
    <Latitude>36.7027777778</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-108.046111111</Longitude>
    <Speed>0.0</Speed>
  </Data>
</Root>
```

Here is the code I am using

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
import MySQLdb
import glob
import os
import shutil
import logging
import sys

localPath = "C:\data"
xmlFiles = glob.glob1(localPath,"*.xml")
for file in xmlFiles:
    a = os.path.join(localPath,file)
    element = etree.parse(a)

    Data = element.xpath('//Root/Data/node()')
    parsedData = [{field.tag: field.text for field in Data} for action in Data]




print parsedData #AttributeError: '_ElementStringResult' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 2):

`'//Root/Data/node()'` will return a list of all the child elements which include text elements as strings which will not have a `text` attribute. If you put a print right after the `Data = ...` you will see something like `['\n    ', <Element FormType at 0x10675fdc0>, '\n    ', ...`.

I would do a filter first such as:

```
Data = [f for f in elem.xpath('//Root/Data/node()') if hasattr(f, 'text')]
```

Then I think the following line could be rewritten as:

```
parsedData = {field.tag: field.text for field in Data}
```

which will give the element tag and text dictionary which I believe is what you want.

Comment: +1 for diagnosing the problem, but it'd be better to revise the query than to keep the existing one and filter its results.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of querying for `//Root/Data/node()`, query for `/Root/Data/*` if you want only elements (as opposed to text nodes) to be returned. (Also, using only a single leading `/` rather than `//` allows the engine to do a cheaper search, rather than needing to look through the whole subtree for an additional `Root`.

Also -- are you sure you *really* want to loop through the entire list of subelements of Data inside your inner loop, rather than looping over only the subelements of a single Data element selected by your outer loop? I think your logic is broken, though it would only be visible if you had a file with more than one `Data` element under `Root`.

Comment: This is a better method to get the elements than mine. +1

Comment: The xml files will only ever have one data element. How can I fix the logic?

Comment: @lodkkx if it's only ever one data element per file it matters less... but I like the line for `parsedData` in Lance's answer more.